# Для чего нужны ; в цикле?

Tags: c#

Есть цикл:

```
int i = 0;
    for(;;){
    i++;
    }
```

Как я понял, он бесконечный.
Но почему тогда я не могу написать вот так:

```
for(int i = 0; i++){
//do smth
}
```

Что **;** делает в коде?

И как тогда лучше:

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length ;i++){
}

int i = 0;
for (; i < text.Length ;){
i++;
}
```

Comment: Это обязательный синтаксический элемент цикла [for](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/statements.md#the-for-statement).

Comment: Потому что это синтаксис оператора for — две точки с запятой должны быть в наличии обязательно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Точка с запятой не просто разделяет элементы, она задает их синтаксический смысл, который определяется их позицией. Пользуясь вашим примером, вы не можете записать оператор цикла как

```
for (int i = 0; i++) ...
```

потому что он был бы проинтерпретирован как

```
for (int i = 0; i++; ) ...
```

(вполне осмысленная запись, хотя в данном случае и приводит к бесконечному цикла), а вы явно имели в виду.

```
for (int i = 0; ; i++) ...
```

Вот если бы не разрешалось пропускать элементы между указанными, то тогда пустых точек с запятой и не понадобилось бы. Такое имеет место, например, в классической форме параметров функции по умолчанию - если аргумент пропущен, все следующий за ним аргументы также должны быть пропущены.

Answer (score 0):

";" служит как разделитель между счетчиком и условием. 
Думаю что разработчикам языка было легче обойти само наличие аргументов чем разделителей